# JFileChooser is not modal under Linux

Tags: java, swing, awt, jfilechooser, mixing

I use Red Hat 6.3 and JRE 1.7.

When opening a file chooser out of an applet it is not modal. When clicking somewhere which is not the file chooser's area it moves behind the applet and the applet is frozen until you minimize the browser to close it.

I experienced already the same problem with modal dialogs in general. But there I found a workaround: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635531/model-dialog-opened-from-applet-is-placed-behind-applet-when-changing-browser-ta).

Is there a way to solve this problem under Linux or is there a Java version where this is problem does not occur?

Comment: Thank you for this idea. We will go in that direction. As we already have a caching mechanism implemented we will start the applet as a standalone application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to solve this problem under Linux

Convert the applet to a frame and (presuming that solves the problem) launch the frame using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

But just to check, do you see the same behavior in [this applet](http://pscode.org/gifanim/#applet)?  It is sand-boxed and not using the `JFileChooser` as such, but if you to try to open or save a file it should pop a UI in a modal dialog.

Answer (score 1):

> When clicking somewhere which is not the file chooser's area it moves
>   behind the applet and the applet is frozen until you minimize the
>   browser to close it.

- then result is correct `JFileChooser` is modal under Linux
- `Swing JComponents` are `lightweight` then (caused) they are always behing `heavyweight AWT Components`
- have to change `Applet` to `JApplet` and all `Components` inside to change to `JComponents`
- more about [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html)